# simple javascript not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I've been having trouble with javascript.  I don't think its my code but possible some outside factor. I've tried the following code on chrome and firefox and I can't get the alert to pop up. Nothing happens when I click the link.  The code below is obviously not on my site, but I'm just using it as an example as to why other parts of my javascript aren't working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
function art() {

alert("jdsklfs");
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<a href='#'>click</a>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Obviously it's not going to work when there is nothing calling `art()`

Answer (score 4):

Well, try calling it ;~)

```
function art() {
 alert("jdsklfs");
}
window.onload = art; //<= now the function will execute on page load
```

or provide the href with an id (`<a href='#' id='artclick'>click</a>`) and assign a click handler to it on load

```
function art() {
 alert("jdsklfs");
}
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('artclick').onclick = art;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the art function.

Simplest, but dirtiest is to have:

```
<a href="#" onclick="art(); return false;">click</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding

`onclick="art();"`

to your anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

Change the

```
<a href='#'>click</a>
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:art();">click</a>
```

Comment: Don't put Javascript in `href`. It's deprecated. Use `onclick` or bind an event handler.

Comment: Deprecated? I wouldn't call it that, it just sends the string to the browser's bar, and AFAIK browsers will always allow javascript in the bar.
It's a bad method I know but it doesn't really matter unless you use internet explorer because there it's pretty delayed.

Answer (score 1):

art() isn't tied to the link in any discernible way.

Answer (score 0):

Change your a tag to:

```
<a href="javascript:art()">click</a>
```

Comment: Don't put Javascript in `href`. It's deprecated. Use `onclick` or bind an event handler.